# How to get available Geolocations in current Zoomlevel in Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

how can i get the Latitude/Longitude values which are currently available in the actual zoomlevel by using GooleMaps API and Android? I do have the GeoLocations of all users on my map but i want to have only the users which are located on my current "Display" (Zoomlevel) therefore i have to know the Geo-Location boundaries for the actual Zoomlevel.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only displaying a few square kilometres and not half the planet, then a decent approximation of the bounding box of your map view can be had with code such as:

```
GeoPoint topLeftGpt;
GeoPoint bottomRightGpt;

topLeftGpt = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(0, 0);
bottomRightGpt = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(mapView.getWidth(),
            mapView.getHeight());
```

If you then use the methods .getLatitudeE6() and .getLongitudeE6() on each of these Geopoints, it will give you the bounding box limits

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int latSpanE6 = mapView.getLatitudeSpan();
int lonSpanE6 = mapView.getLongitudeSpan();
```

EDIT:

Oops, this is all useless without the center of the map:

```
GeoPoint center = mapView.getMapCenter();

int minMapLat = center.getLatitudeE6() - (latSpanE6/2);
int maxMapLat = center.getLatitudeE6() + (latSpanE6/2);
int minMapLon = center.getLongitudeE6() - (lonSpanE6/2);
int maxMapLon = center.getLongitudeE6() + (lonSpanE6/2);
```

Comment: I think you need to divide those spans by 2 before adding/subtracting to/from the centre if you want to do it this way.